# Regex picking to much

Tags: php

This is my json

```
{
  "market_hash_name" : "Chroma 2 Case",
  "price" : "0.12",
  "created_at" : 1463811431
},
{
  "market_hash_name" : "Chroma 2 Case Key",
  "price" : "2.58",
  "created_at" : 1463820978
},
```

im executing this regex

```
        foreach ($prices as $items ){
            foreach ($items as $key => $value){
                if (preg_match("/\A". preg_quote($itemValue['name']) ."/i", $value )) {
                    $x = $items;
                }
            }
        }
```

However when i only search for Chroma 2 Case it also shows Chroma 2 Case Key

How do i adjust my regex to stop after the string is found?

Comment: $ at the end or if you compare it with litteral "string", then you can add \" to match the " at the end

Comment: You appear to be using a regular expression to check whether `$value` exactly matches `$itemValue['name']`. Why can't you just do `if (strtolower($value) == strtolower($itemValue['name']))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex pattern as shown below:

```
...
if (preg_match("/\A". preg_quote($itemValue['name']) ."$/i", $value )) {
// $ - indicates the end of the string
...
```

Comment: $ is end of line. \z is end of string

Comment: @Andreas, `$` - end of the string, `\z` - end of subject (independent of multiline mode)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/\A". preg_quote($itemValue['name']) ."\z/i", $value ))
// or
if (preg_match("/\A". preg_quote($itemValue['name']) ."$/i", $value ))
//or maybe
if (preg_match("/\A". preg_quote($itemValue['name']) ."\"/i", $value ))
```

One of them should work.
The first one matches to end of line.
The second matches to end of string.
The last one matches if the " is in the string. (Very unsure about this one)